# API hooking fails using JMP instruction

Tags: c, windows, winapi, hook, detours

I am intercepting a Win32 function call using JMP instruction which as given at [JMP interception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking#API.2FFunction_Hooking.2FInterception_Using_JMP_Instruction)

I'm able to successfully inject the DLL into the process address space but unable to intercept the call with the new function. Here is the DLL code which is being injected to a process which calls the win32 function. It fails at "VirtualProtect2 failed" with error code 998(Invalid access). Am I doing any mistake in intercepting the call?

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"

#define SIZE 6  
typedef HANDLE (WINAPI *pFindFirstFileA)(LPCSTR,LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA);  // Messagebox protoype
HANDLE WINAPI MyFindFirstFileA(LPCSTR,LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA);            // Our detour
 void BeginRedirect(LPVOID);                                        
 pFindFirstFileA pOrigMBAddress = NULL;                                // address of original
 BYTE oldBytes[SIZE] = {0};                                         // backup
 BYTE JMP[SIZE] = {0};                                              // 6 byte JMP instruction
 DWORD oldProtect, myProtect = PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE; 

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        OutputDebugStringA("dll attach");
                 pOrigMBAddress = (pFindFirstFileA)                      
                 GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("Kernel32.dll"),               // get address of original 
                       "FindFirstFileA");  
                 if(pOrigMBAddress != NULL) 
                 {
                    OutputDebugStringA("dll attach orig address is not null");
                   BeginRedirect(MyFindFirstFileA); 
                 }
                 else
                    OutputDebugStringA("dll attach orig address is null");
                 // start detouring
                 break;  
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
                memcpy(pOrigMBAddress, oldBytes, SIZE);                       // restore backup
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void BeginRedirect(LPVOID newFunction)  
{  
    OutputDebugStringA("dll beginredirect");
    BYTE tempJMP[SIZE] = {0xE9, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0xC3};         // 0xE9 = JMP 0x90 = NOP oxC3 = RET
    memcpy(JMP, tempJMP, SIZE);                                        // store jmp instruction to JMP
    DWORD JMPSize = ((DWORD)newFunction - (DWORD)pOrigMBAddress - 5);  // calculate jump distance
    bool ret = VirtualProtect((LPVOID)pOrigMBAddress, SIZE,                       // assign read write protection
           PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);  
    if(!ret)
        OutputDebugStringA("VirtualProtect1 failed");
    memcpy(oldBytes, pOrigMBAddress, SIZE);                            // make backup
    memcpy(&JMP[1], &JMPSize, 4);                              // fill the nop's with the jump distance (JMP,distance(4bytes),RET)
    memcpy(pOrigMBAddress, JMP, SIZE);                                 // set jump instruction at the beginning of the original function
    ret = VirtualProtect((LPVOID)pOrigMBAddress, SIZE, oldProtect, NULL);
    if(!ret)
    {
        char str[200];
        sprintf(str,"VirtualProtect2 failed %d",GetLastError());
        OutputDebugStringA(str);
    }
    // reset protection
}

HANDLE WINAPI MyFindFirstFileA(LPCSTR lpFileName,LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA lpFindFileData) 
{  
    OutputDebugStringA("success hook");
    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)pOrigMBAddress, SIZE, myProtect, NULL);     // assign read write protection
    memcpy(pOrigMBAddress, oldBytes, SIZE);                            // restore backup
    HANDLE retValue = FindFirstFileA(lpFileName,lpFindFileData);       // get return value of original function
    memcpy(pOrigMBAddress, JMP, SIZE);                                 // set the jump instruction again
    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)pOrigMBAddress, SIZE, oldProtect, NULL);    // reset protection
    return retValue;                                                   // return original return value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The msdn description of VirtualProtect at the link below says that VirtualProtect fails if the lpfOldProtect parameter is NULL and it looks like you are using NULL for it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898(v=vs.85).aspx

"lpflOldProtect [out]
A pointer to a variable that receives the previous access protection value of the first page in the specified region of pages. **If this parameter is NULL or does not point to a valid variable, the function fails.**"